A Script to Right Align and then Center the Text in Indesign Table
I'm having a trouble dealing with so many tables in indesign, there are approximately around 200 tables with the same characteristics. I'm wondering if anyone know any indesign script to right align all the text in all cells in a column of an indesign table and then center the text to the middle of the cell based on the longest text among every cell that is included in the column. Simply, a financial table format, where it's right aligned, but at the same time it's centered. Thank you!
an indesign script that right align and center the text in all cells in every table

https://chatgpt.com/share/07f0b7e6-5ebc-4c83-9f8a-bf900773b131

If you mean to align digits, the classic way how it can be done is to add one or several the "figure spaces" (the # at the screenshot) at the start of every short line and align the column by the center.
In a proper font all digits have the same width and InDesign uses it as a width for the special space "figure space". It makes possible to align the digits by the right side (see the second column on the screenshot, it's aligned by the center actually).

Of course it makes sense to add the "figure spaces" via a script. But there are details the actual code depends on. I will glad to help if you share a screenshot or idml-file with a sample of your tables.
For example it could be something like this:
var cells = app.selection;
if (!(cells[0] instanceof Cell)) {
    alert('You have to select one or several cells');
    exit();
}

var cell, para, len;
var max = 0;

// get the max length from selected cells
for (var c=0; c<cells.length; c++) {
    cell = cells[c];
    for (var p=0; p<cell.paragraphs.length; p++) {
        para = cell.paragraphs[p];
        if (para.characters.length > max) max = para.characters.length;
    }
}

// add the 'figure spaces' to all lines in selected cells
for (var c=0; c<cells.length; c++) {
    cell = cells[c];
    for (var p=0; p<cell.paragraphs.length; p++) {
        para = cell.paragraphs[p];
        len = max - para.characters.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
            para.insertionPoints[0].contents = SpecialCharacters.FIGURE_SPACE;
        }
    }
}

This script takes selected cells, gets the maximum number of characters in the longest line, and adds 'figure spaces' at the start of every line in those cells to make the lengths of all lines equal.
Here is the full automated variant of the same algorithm (based on the comment of @user1754036). It iterates through all tables of the active document, you don't need to select anything.
// Function to align and center text based on the longest text in a column function
function formatColumn(column) {

    var pgfs = column.cells.everyItem().paragraphs.everyItem().getElements();
    var len;
    var max_len = 0;

    // Get the max paragraph length from the cells of the column
    for (var i=0; i<pgfs.length; i++) {
        if (pgfs[i].characters.length > max_len) {
            max_len = pgfs[i].characters.length;
        }
    }

    // Add the 'figure spaces' to the short paragraphs in the cells
    for (var i=0; i<pgfs.length; i++) {
        pgfs[i].justification = Justification.CENTER_ALIGN;
        len = max_len - pgfs[i].characters.length;
        while(len--) {
            pgfs[i].insertionPoints[0].contents = SpecialCharacters.FIGURE_SPACE;
        }
    }
}

// Main script execution
function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var tables = doc.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().getElements();

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        var columns = tables[i].columns.everyItem().getElements();

        // Iterate through each column in the table
        for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {
            formatColumn(columns[c]);
        }
    }
}

// Run the main script
app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, app.activeScript.displayName);

